# Reuse of table cells issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I believe I am incorrectly implementing `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I have a `UISlider` that is hidden by default and appears when a button is pressed in the table cell. When I press the button in the first cell,the slider appears not only in the first cell, but in every third  cell when I scroll down. I am currently avoiding this by reseting the slider's hidden property to `YES` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I also do this for other views in the cell I need hidden by default. This creates a new issue when I scroll back up to the first cell, the slider is hidden because the property is reset in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

SongsCustomCell *songCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (songCell == nil) {
    songCell = [[SongsCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"new cell created");
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [parseTrackArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString *trackTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"trackTitle"];
NSString *trackLink = [dictionary objectForKey:@"trackStreamLink"];
songCell.trackLinkString = trackLink;
songCell.trackTitleString = trackTitle;
[songCell.trackTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:22]];
songCell.trackTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", trackTitle];

songCell.playButton.hidden = NO;
songCell.playbackSlider.hidden = YES;
songCell.playerHasLoaded = NO;
songCell.moviePlayer.view.hidden = YES;

return songCell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the hidden / unhidden status of your slider in your data model somewhere, and then set the slider's visibility appropriately from that in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If only one slider is visible at once, you can store the index path as an ivar in your view controller, if not then you will need to have another key in your dictionary holding an NSNumber bool or something.

Comment: I understand now, but I'm having trouble implementing. I don't think I can use `NSDictionary *dictionary` b/c it gets recreated in cellFor...  Can you give more detail please?

Comment: I meant the dictionary currently held in your prseTrackArray -  if this was mutable, you could set a new key / value pair in it when your button was pressed in each row. How many rows do you have, and does your table view have sections, and can more than one slider be shown at once?

Comment: The amount of rows is dynamic. There are around a 100 rows now (parseTrackArray.count), but will increase over time into the thousands as objects are added daily to parseTrackArray. The tableView does not have sections and more than one slider will be shown at once.

Comment: To add an object to a dictionary that is in array, I need to query the dictionary, `setObject:YES forKey:'sliderEnabled'`, then replace the new  dictionary with the old one in parseTrackArray?

Comment: Yes, that will work - but you'll need to add it as an NSNumber - [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]

Comment: Im away from my mac at the moment but will be able to do sample code later on if you need it

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your cells are being reused when you are scrolling down. So when your slider is visible for a cell thats is scrolling out of view, that cell will be reused and thus the slider is still visible.

To avoid this implement `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell to reset your slider as soon as your cell is being reused.

Next to that you still need to store the state of the slider in your model, so you are able to restore that state once that object is coming back in view.

Nevertjeless its a good practice to set the default state of your custom cell in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: This will result in the same behavior as just setting hidden to YES in cellForRow...

Comment: @Matt, yes you are right, you still need to save the state of the slider in the datasource model, I added some more details

Comment: Thank you. What method do you suggest for storing the state of the slider?

Comment: In your dictionary of the parseTrackArray, add a key 'sliderEnabled' ,or something like that, for each dictionary in your array. And when you push the button you set this key to YES for that item, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you check this value again